# My custom .desktop file appears in Dash as a text file

Tags: unity-dash, .desktop, matlab

I recently installed MATLAB on my computer. I found that while I could easily start MATLAB from the terminal, there was no executable file I could double click on to run it. So I created a Bash script to run MATLAB and then created a .desktop file and saved it in `/usr/share/applications/`. Here's the content of that .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MATLAB
Hidden=false
Exec=Desktop/Programs/scripts/runMatlab.sh
Icon=/usr/share/icons/matlabIcon.jpg
Categories=Application;
```

If I look inside `/usr/share/applications/`, I indeed see an executable file with the name MATLAB and the appropriate icon, and if I double click on it MATLAB will run just fine. However, if I type MATLAB into Dash, matlab.desktop appears as a text file. It doesn't have the correct name (MATLAB) or correct icon, and if I click on it Gedit will open instead of the file being executed.

How can I fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 by the way.

Comment: Have you set the executable flag?

Comment: @ByteCommander I'm sorry, but I don't know what an executable flag is.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you added the execution permission to your matlab.desktop by running `chmod +x matlab.desktop`? Same procedure as for .sh shell scripts.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes, I did.

Comment: Would you run `desktop-file-validate matlab.desktop`? It should show whether there are any errors in the .desktop file. If there is no output, the file is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a good look in Dash, you will find out that `matlab.desktop` does not appear as an application, but the *file*  `matlab.desktop` appears in *search*, or *recently used*, since you obviously edited it.

#### The error

The reason is that Dash does not see it as a *valid* `.desktop` file for (at least) the following reason:

- You should not use relative paths in a `.desktop` file (`Desktop/Programs/scripts/runMatlab.sh` is relative), but *absolute* paths.

Other possible reasons could be an invalid icon path or the fact that you call the script without the preceding `sh` (if the script is not executable, but given the other information in your question, that seems not to be the case).

#### Notes

- Another thing is that *if* you store the script on what appears to be a local directory, you should not store the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, but in `~/.local/share/applications`.
- There is no need to make a `.desktop` file executable if you run it from Dash or the Launcher. Most launchers in either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications` are not. Only if you locate it on- and run it from your Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, move the .desktop file to `/usr/share/applications/` (global launchers, needs root permission to move file) or to `~/.local/share/applications/` (only for the current user).*
**EDIT:** *When you run desktop-file-install, this is not necessary as it automatically copies the file to /usr/share/applications/*

Then, after checking your .desktop file for errors with `desktop-file-install filename.desktop` (no output means no errors, but even some warnings may not prevent the launcher from working),
you add it to the Unity dash by running `sudo desktop-file-install filename.desktop` (**EDIT:** *root privileges required to access /usr/share/applications/ where global launchers are stored*). Please note that this command might add some lines to the original .desktop file.

I hope this solved your problem. Greetings!
(Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)