# Why do portable app icons disappear from Unity launcher after restart?

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop

I downloaded SublimeText and placed it in my home folder. I locked sublimetext to the Unity launcher, but when I restart my PC the icon disappears from the launcher.

Why is this happening? Can I solve this somehow?

Comment: You should create a .desktop file and install it to your launcher. The procedure is described there: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles you can also read my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/578439/367990) and its corresponding question.

Comment: Did you install it from the tarball or the .deb installer? @Bytecommander : both versions come with a `.desktop` file.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't know as I don't have this app. But maybe the files have to get installed as it is described both in the article and in my linked answer?

Comment: @ByteCommander I looked into both the tarball and the .deb installer of the Sublime download page: http://www.sublimetext.com/3. both *do* have a `.desktop` file. He probably used the first option, looking at "placed it in my home folder", and the .desktop file probably points to the wrong location or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.desktop` file is needed. One way is to install `sublime` text editor via webupd8 ppa.

Version 3 ([url](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/sublime_text_3)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Version 2 ([url](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/sublime_text_2), not tested, but should work):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

This adds a `.desktop` file to `/usr/share/applications/`.

Alternatively, add a `.desktop` file to `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` manually. This should point to your binary.

This is the `.desktop` file from version 3 on my system:

```
# cat /usr/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;Utility;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Comment: It seems a bit overdone to post a .desktop file, while all versions come with a .desktop file. If he needs an edited version, he can simply copy the one in `/usr/share/applications` or place the one that comes in the tarball in `~/.local/share/applications`, depending on how he installed.

Comment: It is not clear to me which version is installed. And since in the tarball v2.0.2 from http://www.sublimetext.com/ there is no `.desktop` file, I added one.

Comment: Ah, I see. we need more info from OP. I assumed he would install the latest version. Without a .desktop file, he would however not be able to lock it to the launcher *at all*.

Comment: You are right. But since sublime 3 is beta, still, this made me suspicious...