# integrate apps to ubuntu without Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-installation

I want to install a program which is not inside ubuntu Software : [Processing](http://processing.org/).
I downloaded the tar.gz package, followed [this doc](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/processing) - create a *processing.desktop* file inside `/usr/share/applications/` - and the program works from the terminal.

inside processing.desktop :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF­8
Name=Processing
GenericName=Processing
Comment=Un environnement de développement pour le langage Processing
Icon=/usr/share/processing/processing.png
Exec=/usr/share/processing/processing-2.2.1/processing
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Development;Electronics' > processing.desktop
```

But I would like an integration : Processing have to be in the apps (win+A) and the extensions file had to be recognize.

Comment: Would you please add the contents of your .desktop file to your questions (edit it) and leave me a comment (@ByteCommander) when you finished?

Comment: I did it, but know my .desktop file is the suggestion of david foerster

Comment: Try the command `desktop-file-install`. I described it in my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/578439/367990). Don't hesitate to upvote if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my `/usr/local/share/applications/processing.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Processing Development Environment
Exec=processing %F
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=pde
Categories=Development;IDE
MimeType=application/x-processing-sketch
```

Assuming `processing` is in your `$PATH`. Otherwise you need to specify the executable path after `Exec=`. There's no “standard“ MIME type for processing, so I made one up (`application/x-processing-sketch`). You also need to [add it to `mimeapps.list`](/a/190927/175814).

Alternatively you can look at the answers to [How to make file association (not with CLI tool/command)?](/q/61744/175814) how to create a file association for your user account only.

A suitable icon pack can be found at http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~foerstda/libs/pde-icons.tar and installed with

```
sudo tar -xf pde-icons.tar -C /
```

or simply

```
wget -O - http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~foerstda/libs/pde-icons.tar | sudo tar -x -C /
```

Comment: thx, I did it, Processing is now inside "apps". but nothing for the extension .pde. I copy this line `application/x-processing-sketch=processing.desktop;` just under _[Added Associations] ...

Comment: we never said "recognize the extension **.pde** " ?

Comment: It says so in your question: “and the extensions file had to be recognize.” What are you trying to get at? I don't understand.

Comment: when I launch a .pde file I want it opens with Processing, currently the file is open with Gedit. thx

Comment: see, if my update helps you.

Comment: ok thx, I made it. the association file was done without editing mimetype (it didn't work here). And I had to specify the path after _icon_ in the processing.desktop.

Comment: That's odd. The order of the "properties" inside one section of a `.desktop` file shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: no, the exact path of my .png file for the icon :)